# How to delete from queryset without deleting the original model itself in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

So, I have two model sets like the following:

```py
# User class
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    ...
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=50, null=False, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(verbose_name="password", max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="name", max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name="nickname", max_length=50, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(verbose_name="birthday", max_length=8)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(verbose_name="profile picture", default="default_profile.png")

    USERNAME_FIELD='email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['password', 'name', 'username', 'date_of_birth']

    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        through='Relationship',
        related_name='followees',
        through_fields=('to_user', 'from_user'),
        )

    @property
    def followers(self):
        follower_relationship = self.relationship_to_user.filter(relationship_type=Relationship.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_FOLLOWING)
        follower_list = follower_relationship.values_list('from_user', flat=True)
        followers = User.objects.filter(pk__in=follower_list)
        return followers

    @property
    def followees(self):
        followee_relationship = self.relationship_from_user.filter(relationship_type=Relationship.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_FOLLOWING)
        followee_list = followee_relationship.values_list('to_user', flat=True)
        followees = User.objects.filter(pk__in=followee_list)
        return followees        
    
    def follow(self, to_user):
        self.relationship_from_user.create(
            to_user = to_user,
            relationship_type='f'
            )
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

```py
# Relationships class
class Relationship(models.Model):
    RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_FOLLOWING = 'f'
    RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_BLOCKED = 'b'
    CHOICE_TYPE = (
        (RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_FOLLOWING, '팔로잉'),
        (RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_BLOCKED, '차단'),
        )
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='relationship_from_user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='relationship_to_user',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    relationship_type=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICE_TYPE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.from_user} follows {self.to_user}, type={self.relationship_type}"
```

And in the `python manage.py shell`, I did the following:

```
>>> user1 = User.objects.get(id=1)    # user1@gmail.com 
>>> user2 = User.objects.get(id=2)    # user2@gmail.com
>>> user3 = User.objects.get(id=3)    # user3@gmail.com
>>> user1.follow(user2)
>>> user1.follow(user3)
>>> user1.followees
<QuerySet [<User: user2@gmail.com>, <User: user3@gmail.com>]>
```

Now my main question is related to the `user1.followees`. I want to delete `<User: user3@gmail.com>` from the `user1.followees` queryset without deleting also the user from the database. I've tried the following:

```
>>> user1.followees[1].delete()                         # 1
>>> user1.followees.exclude(email='user3@gmail.com')    # 2
```

The first try(#1) does delete the user3 from the queryset, but also deletes the user itself from the database and prints outs the following (The print might not be the same when you do it because this is the third or fourth time I've been trying this on my own):

```
(4, {'accounts.Relationship': 3, 'accounts.User': 1})
```

The second try(#2) does exclude the designated user and returns a new queryset without the user, but the original queryset is not altered when I access it, as shown in the following:

```
>>> user1.followees.exclude(email='user3@gmail.com')
<QuerySet [<User: user2@gmail.com>]>
>>> user1.followees
<QuerySet [<User: user2@gmail.com>, <User: user3@gmail.com>]>
```

Comment: Use models.SET_NULL instead of cascade
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SET_NULL

Comment: I'll try this and see what happens

Comment: @madzohan This still does delete the user itself. I replaced the `models.CASCADE` with `models.SET_NULL` in the `from_user` field and `to_user` field in the `Relationship` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manytomany has specific methods for adding and removing relations.

```
user1.followees.remove(user3)
```

Also, unless you need custom logic in the `follow()` method, you can probably just use `user1.followees.add(user3)`.

`user1.followees.clear()` can remove all followees.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: When I try the remove method, `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'remove'` comes up

Comment: Also, both the `add` and `clear` raises the AttributeError.

Comment: You have both `related_name='followees',` and a custom property that overwrites the django built in methods `def followees(self):`

Comment: Try changing the name of method `followees` and see if the built in methods will work?

Comment: Wow this a better approach and a better answer than the one that I found just before. This really helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help out!  Hopefully you were able to reduce your code :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I was accessing the user itself from what I was doing:

```
>>> user1.followees[0] --> This accesses the user who's in the followees[0], not the relatioship itself
```

Therefore, when I try deleting the queryset, I'm accessing the user itself, so I'm actually deleting the queryset **and** the **user itself**. Therefore, my solution was to access the **Relationship**, not the user. I did the following:

```
>>> Relationship.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Relationship: user1@gmail.com follows user2@gmail.com, type=f>, <Relationship: user1@gmail.com follows user3@gmail.com type=f>]>
>>> Relationship.objects.all()[0]
<QuerySet [<Relationship: user1@gmail.com follows user3@gmail.com, type=f>]>
>>> Relationship.objects.all()[0].delete()
(1, {'accounts.Relationship': 1})
```

and checking the Relationship model and the user1 relationship:

```
>>> Relationship.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<Relationship: user1@gmail.com follows user3@gmail.com type=f>]>
>>> user1.followees
>>> <QuerySet [<User: user2@gmail.com>]>
```

This was the answer!

** This method was possible, but the answer that @user1464664 gave is a much better one, so I suggest looking into that one